# Factoring Quadratic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics

I have used the substitution P = dy/dx to solve a first-order D.E of degree 4, so I got this:

[image]

I have to show that the above statement can be written as:

[image]

I tried to factor out first by taking p a common factor
[image]

then try to find the roots of the quadratic equation

[image]

but I never worked with such quadratic equations, any hint please how to factor the above form?

Comment: I upvoted this question specifically _because_ there are some errors in the arithmetic. Students make these kinds of errors frequently, and you can learn from these mistakes--as can others who see this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be a little more careful when you "take out a common factor".
$$\begin{split}
P^4 - P(x+2y+1)P^3 + (x + 2&y + 2xy)P^2 - 2xyP \neq \\
& P^3 - P((x+2y+1)P^2 + (x+2y+2xy)P - 2xy).
\end{split}$$
The $P^4$ term is missing entirely from the right-hand side, there's a $P^3$ term in
its place, and the signs of $(x + 2y + 2xy)P^2$ and $2xyP$ have been flipped.

Since you have been *given* the factorization and merely need to show it's true,
you can work the problem from the other end.
Multiply everything out into individual terms in $x$, $y$, and $P$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(P-1)(P-x)(P-2y)
 & = & P(P-1)(P^2 - xP - 2yP + 2xy) \\
 & = & P(P^2(P-1) - xP(P-1) - 2yP(P-1) + 2xy(P-1)) \\
 & = & P((P^3 - P^2) - (xP^2 - xP) - (2yP^2 - 2yP) + (2xyP - 2xy)) \\
 & = & P(P^3 - P^2 - xP^2 + xP - 2yP^2 + 2yP + 2xyP - 2xy) \\
 & = & P^4 - P^3 - xP^3 + xP^2 - 2yP^3 + 2yP^2 + 2xyP^2 - 2xyP.
\end{eqnarray}$$
I'm taking more steps than I usually would here so that I can make very clear
exactly where each $+$ and $-$ sign comes from.
Eventually it gets easier to tell what sign each term should have so you won't need
to write it in such excruciating detail, but until you get that facility,
this level of detail may help.

Gather all the terms in $P^3$ together, and likewise for the terms in $P^2$,
and factor out the powers of $P$:
$$\begin{split}
P^4 - P^3 - & xP^3 + xP^2 - 2yP^3 + 2yP^2 + 2xyP^2 - 2xyP \\
 & = P^4 - P^3 - xP^3 - 2yP^3 + xP^2 + 2yP^2 + 2xyP^2 - 2xyP \\
 & = P^4 + (-P^3 - xP^3 - 2yP^3) + (xP^2 + 2yP^2 + 2xyP^2) - 2xyP \\
 & = P^4 - (P^3 + xP^3 + 2yP^3) + (xP^2 + 2yP^2 + 2xyP^2) - 2xyP \\
 & = P^4 - (1 + x + 2y)P^3 + (x + 2y + 2xy)P^2 - 2xyP.
\end{split}$$
Again, excruciating detail just to illustrate exactly why all the signs are what they are.
Then, since equality is transitive,
$$
P(P-1)(P-x)(P-2y) = P^4 - (1 + x + 2y)P^3 + (x + 2y + 2xy)P^2 - 2xyP.
$$
Notice that $1 + x + 2y = x + 2y + 1$ and you can easily get the exact form
of your original equation.

Comment: I't now more clear to me how to do it, thank you for your time and effort in explaining I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
P\left(P^3 - (x+2y+1)P^2 + (x+2y+2xy)P - 2xy\right) = 0
$$
lets rewrite as
$$
P\left(P^3 - (x+2y)P^2 - P^2 + (x+2y)P + 2xyP - 2xy\right)\\
=P\left(P^2(P-1)-(x+2y)P(P-1)+ 2xy(P - 1)\right)=
P(P-1)\left(P^2-(x+2y)P+ 2xy\right) =0
$$

Now
$$
\left(P^2-(x+2y)P+ 2xy\right) = (P - 2y)(P - x)
$$ 
You are done
$$
P^4 - (x+2y+1)P^3 + (x+2y+2xy)P^2 - 2xyP  =\\
P(P-1)(P-2y)(P-x) = 0
$$